# Скачивание нескольких файлов одновременно, возможность отслеживать их прогресс по отдельности

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Хочу сделать приложение, которое будет скачивать несколько файлов одновременно. Слева - листбокс, в котором можно выбрать объект. Справа - информация о выбранном объекте, текстовое поле для ввода ссылки на файл, кнопка скачивания, отмены скачивания, прогресс скачивания и т.п. Вопрос: как это правильно реализовать, используя MVVM?

Model:

```
public class Model
{
    private readonly WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    private readonly Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    public event Action<long> FileSizeChanged;
    public event Action<long, TimeSpan> DownloadBytesChanged;
    public event Action<double> ProgressPercentageChanged;
    public event Action DownloadComplete;

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public void DownloadFile(string url, bool openAfterDownload)
    {
        if (webClient.IsBusy)
            throw new Exception("Данный клиент для скачивания занят");
        try
        {
            var startDownloading = DateTime.UtcNow;
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            if (!SelectFolder(Path.GetFileName(url)+Path.GetExtension(url), out var filePath))
                throw DownloadingError();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += (o, args) =>
            {
                ProgressPercentageChanged?.Invoke(args.ProgressPercentage);
                FileSizeChanged?.Invoke(args.TotalBytesToReceive);
                DownloadBytesChanged?.Invoke(args.BytesReceived, DateTime.UtcNow - startDownloading);
                if (args.ProgressPercentage >= 100 && openAfterDownload)
                    Process.Start(filePath);
            };
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += (o, args) => DownloadComplete?.Invoke();
            stopWatch.Start();
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw DownloadingError();
        }
    }

    public void CancelDownloading()
    {
        webClient.CancelAsync();
        webClient.Dispose();
        DownloadComplete?.Invoke();
    }

    private static Exception DownloadingError()
        => new Exception("Ошибка при скачивании! Проверьте URL\n и не забудьте указать путь");

    private static bool SelectFolder(string fileName, out string filePath)
    {
        var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            InitialDirectory = "c:\\",
            FileName = fileName,
            Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*"
        };
        filePath = "";
        if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() != true) return false;
        filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;
        return true;
    }
}
```

ViewModel(Уже была предпринята попытка это реализовать, но безуспешно):

```
class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string url;
    private RelayCommand downloadCommand;
    private RelayCommand cancelCommand;
    private double progressBarValue;
    private string bytesReceived;
    private string bytesTotal;
    private string speed;
    private string time;
    private string error;
    //private readonly Model model;
    private long totalBytes;
    private Model selectedGame;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Games { get; set; }

    public MainVM()
    {
        Games = new ObservableCollection<Model>();

        Model Game1 = new Model { Name = "Game1" };
        Model Game2 = new Model { Name = "Game2" };
        Games.Add(Game1);
        Games.Add(Game2);
        SelectedGame = Games[0];
        SelectedGame.FileSizeChanged += bytes => BytesTotal = PrettyBytes(totalBytes = bytes);
        SelectedGame.DownloadBytesChanged += (bytes, time) =>
        {
            BytesReceived = PrettyBytes(bytes);
            Speed = DownloadingSpeed(bytes, time);
            Time = DownloadingTime(bytes, totalBytes, time);
        };
        SelectedGame.ProgressPercentageChanged += percentage => ProgressBarValue = percentage;
        SelectedGame.DownloadComplete += () =>
        {
            BytesReceived = "";
            BytesTotal = "";
            Speed = "";
            Time = "";
            ProgressBarValue = 0;
        };
    }

    public Model SelectedGame
    {
        get => selectedGame;
        set
        {
            if (value == selectedGame) return; 
            selectedGame = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedGame));
        }
    }

    public string Error
    {
        get => error;
        private set
        {
            error = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Error));
        }
    }
    public string URL
    {
        get => url;
        set
        {
            url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(URL));
        }
    }

    public bool OpenDownloadedFile { get; set; }

    public double ProgressBarValue
    {
        get => progressBarValue;
        set
        {
            progressBarValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ProgressBarValue));
        }
    }

    public string BytesTotal
    {
        get => bytesTotal;
        private set
        {
            bytesTotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BytesTotal));
        }
    }

    public string BytesReceived
    {
        get => bytesReceived;
        private set
        {
            bytesReceived = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(BytesReceived));
        }
    }

    public string Speed
    {
        get => speed;
        private set
        {
            speed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Speed));
        }
    }

    public string Time
    {
        get => time;
        private set
        {
            time = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Time));
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand DownloadCommand =>
        downloadCommand ??
        (downloadCommand = new RelayCommand(DownloadButton_Click));

    public RelayCommand CancelCommand =>
        cancelCommand ??
        (cancelCommand = new RelayCommand(CancelButton_Click));

    private void DownloadButton_Click(object obj)
    {
        if (url == null && url == "") return;
        try
        {
            //model.DownloadFile(url, OpenDownloadedFile);
            SelectedGame.DownloadFile(url, OpenDownloadedFile);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Error = e.Message;
        }
    }

    private void CancelButton_Click(object obj)
    {
        if (url != null || url != "")
            //model.CancelDownloading();
            SelectedGame.CancelDownloading();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string prop = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
    private static string PrettyBytes(double bytes)
    {
        if (bytes < 1024)
            return bytes + "Б";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 2))
            return (bytes / 1024).ToString("F" + 2) + "КБ";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 3))
            return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 2)).ToString("F" + 2) + "МБ";
        if (bytes < Math.Pow(1024, 4))
            return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 5)).ToString("F" + 2) + "ГБ";
        return (bytes / Math.Pow(1024, 4)).ToString("F" + 2) + "ТБ";
    }

    public static string DownloadingSpeed(long received, TimeSpan time)
    {
        return ((double)received / 1024 / 1024 / time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 2) + " МБ/СЕК";
    }
    public static string DownloadingTime(long received, long total, TimeSpan time)
    {
        var receivedD = (double) received;
        var totalD = (double) total;
        return ((totalD / (receivedD / time.TotalSeconds)) - time.TotalSeconds).ToString("F" + 1) + "СЕК";
    }
}
```

View:

```
<Window x:Class="DownloadingFiles.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DownloadingFiles"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainVM/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Canvas Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="4" DataContext="{Binding SelectedGame, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding URL, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            FontSize="40" Width="424"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Content="DOWNLOAD" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}" Canvas.Left="429" Canvas.Top="-2" Width="157"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Content="{Binding Error, Mode=OneWay}" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="45" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.Left="401" Canvas.Top="123" Width="184" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="30" Content="Открыть после скачивания"
                  IsChecked="{Binding OpenDownloadedFile, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="80"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Content="CANCEL" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Command ="{Binding CancelCommand}" Canvas.Left="429" Canvas.Top="50" Width="157"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding Time, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" Width="69" Canvas.Left="310" Canvas.Top="277" RenderTransformOrigin="2.284,1.56"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding Speed, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" Width="193" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="277"/>
        <ProgressBar Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Value="{Binding ProgressBarValue}"  Foreground="#AAA1C8" Height="75" Width="424" Canvas.Left="15" Canvas.Top="335"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Content="{Binding ProgressBarValue}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Canvas.Left="230" Canvas.Top="339"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding BytesReceived, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top" Canvas.Left="448" Canvas.Top="299" Width="137"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Content="{Binding BytesTotal, Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="30" FontFamily="./#Sochi2014" Height="44" Canvas.Left="448" Canvas.Top="344" Width="137" />
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Height="40" Width="186" Canvas.Left="22" Canvas.Top="202"/>
    </Canvas>

    <ListBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Games}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGame, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action<object> _execute;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute = null)
    {
        if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter ?? "<N/A>");
    }
```

Comment: Попытка была, а в чем проблема то возникла?

Comment: @Сергей как минимум, не работают кнопки. При переключении между объектами слетает введённая ссылка. Также bindingexpression path error всех байдингов

Comment: Вы понимаете, что задаете вопрос "Как скачать файлы", а сами ругаетесь на  ошибки в привязках? Пожалуйста, задавайте вопросы так, что бы они содержали всего 1 конкретный вопрос с подробным описанием (`bindingexpression` и др.). Поймите нас, не каждый сможет на глаз определить где проблема, а вы это еще усложнили тем, что намешали все в одной куче без каких либо объяснений.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Изначально программа была для скачивания одного файла и данной проблемы не было. После моей попытки сделать скачивания нескольких файлов, вылезла данная ошибка. Уверен, что ответ на мой главный вопрос поможет избавиться и от перечисленных мною проблем